# Why is my CSS drop-down menu opening behind a DIV in IE7?

Tags: css, cross-browser

Here's a link that shows the problem: http://xotics.equivalenceclass.com/test.php

In IE7 it opens behind the blue "home-banner" and "home-banner-wrapper" DIV. I'm not sure why. When removing the background image for "home-banner", but I don't believe that this solves the problem. I tried playing with the z-index CSS properties of the elements to no avail.

Comment: Could you please post the css.

Comment: Yes post some simplified HTML + corresponding CSS. It takes unnecessary time for people to find out what belongs where...

Answer (score 5):

It's because you have `position: relative` on the containing div.  The z-indexes will apply only within that div.  Add a z-index to #header and it should work.

Comment: I love this site. Sometime even the most simple solutions slip your mind!